# 3 Character Long Alphanumeric Regex Not Working

Tags: javascript, regex

So I am trying to use a regular expression to check against strings but it doesn't seem to be working properly.

Basically I want it to match a alpha-numeric string that is exactly 3 characters long. The expression I am using below does not seem to be working for this:

```
const msg = message.content;
const regex = /[A-Za-z0-9]{3}/g;

if (msg.match(regex)) {
    // Do something
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `^` and `$` for the start-of-string anchor and end-of-string anchor, respectively - otherwise, for example, for `#123`, the `123` will match, and it will pass the regex. You also might consider using the `i` flag rather than repeat `A-Za-z`, and you can use `\d` instead of `0-9`.

It looks like you just want to check whether the string passes the regex's test or not, in which case `.test` (evaluates to a boolean) might be a bit more appropriate than `.match`. Also, either way, there's no need for the global flag if you're just checking whether a string passes a regex:

```
const regex = /^[a-z\d]{3}$/i;
if (regex.test(msg)) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you!